# jscript and jquery and Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have userscript. I recentyly added jquery to it.

Before I added jquery that line was working:

```
document.getElementById("servertime").removeAttribute("id");
```

but now after I added jquery (jquery is working) this line gives me error that it is undefined.
Why before jquery it was working and now it it not?

Comment: Who knows? You'll need to show your code. Is jQuery removing the ID from the element, or the element itself?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMGds/)

Comment: Show us your HTML, JavaScript and jQuery code.

Comment: @PenchoIlchev This is simple greasemonkey userscript with // [@]require   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js       I'm not using jquery anywhare in my user script now just to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is weird, but you can now use jQuery to do this:

```
$("#servertime").removeAttr("id");
```

Comment: Maybe your error isn't happening on that line? Your code is pretty basic, nothing can go wrong there unless the DOM has somehow been altered by jQuery and "servertime" element no longer exists.

Comment: It works when I remove [@]require ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Well, if it's of any help, I just tried using your code with and without jquery (using your above include line) and it worked. So maybe you should look into other conflicts that may be causing this.